# com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter version question

Tags: spring-boot-starter

I am using spring version: 4.2.5 release and spring boot version 1.5.3 release.

Please let me know what is the right version of com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter I should use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming the tags on the pom.xml file, you'll see that

- [1.12](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/blob/jasypt-spring-boot-parent-1.12/pom.xml) uses Spring Boot 1.5.1-RELEASE
- [1.13](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/blob/jasypt-spring-boot-parent-1.13/pom.xml) skips straight to 1.5.4-RELEASE, and it stays on that version up to [1.17](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/blob/jasypt-spring-boot-parent-1.17/pom.xml)
- then [1.18](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/blob/jasypt-spring-boot-parent-1.18/pom.xml) jumps to 1.5.10-RELEASE

and the next tag is 2.0.0 which switches to Spring Boot 2.0.0.

So there are no jasypt-spring-boot-starter versions that have Spring Boot 1.5.3 specifically, but I expect you could make that version work with any 1.x release from 1.12 onwards. I'd choose 1.17 or 1.18 I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Latest version on 06/06/2023